# What is the purpose of calling htmlspecialchars in getRefererUrl?

Tags: magento

I encountered what seems like a bug in Magento, but I'm hoping someone smarter than me can explain this.

In VoteController.php, the function `addAction` calls `_redirectReferer` on it's last line.  The purpose of this is to redirect the user back to the original page after voting in a Magento poll.

`_redirectReferer` calls `_getRefererUrl`, which grabs the referring url from several places.  One of the last things this function does is to call `escapeUrl` on the URL string.  `escapeUrl` is a wrapper for `htmlspecialchars`.

The result is a URL like `example.com/?a=b&c=d` becomes `example.com/?a=b&amp;c=d` (notice the broken ampersand).

What is the purpose of calling htmlspecialchars on a URL?

---

**Resources**

`addAction`:  /app/code/core/Mage/Poll/controllers/VoteController.php
`_redirectReferer` and `_getRefererUrl`: /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php
`escapeUrl`: /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Helper/Abstract.php

Comment: To recreate my problem, create a page with a Magento poll.  Visit the page with 2+ query string parameters set (ex: ?a=b&c=d), and vote on the poll.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Background:** `&amp;` is the required html entity representation for the ampersand character; otherwise the browser assumes whatever follows the `&` in the source is an entity representation. Ref http://www.w3.org/QA/2005/04/php-session#background .

This is good whenever a URL is being rendered, but not ideal when a redirect is being calculated server-side and applied to the response object. Therefore **this is a bug** and a good excuse to rewrite the `core/data` helper to escape this the proper way.

POC for anyone too lazy :-) to set up a poll:

```
<?php
include 'app/Mage.php';
Mage::app();

$p = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParams();

if (empty($p)) {
    $refererUrl = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getServer('HTTP_REFERER').'?foo=bar&baz=bip';
    $refererUrl = Mage::helper('core')->escapeUrl($refererUrl);
    Mage::app()->getResponse()->setRedirect($refererUrl);
    Mage::app()->getResponse()->sendResponse();
    exit;
}

var_dump($p);
```

Comment: Thanks Ben.  FYI, I read this whole thing in your voice after watching your videos for 40 hours. =D

Comment: I hope you made fun of "The Marketing Department" whilst doing it :-) - and I hope someone paid you well / in beer for your time.